# Prove that the limiting value of $AQ$ when $P$ moves upto $A$ is double the diameter of the circle.

Tags: geometry, limits

Through a point $A$ on the circle,a chord $AP$ is drawn and on the tangent at A a point $T$ is taken such that $AT=AP$.If $TP$ produced meet the diameter through $A$ at $Q$,prove that the limiting value of $AQ$ when $P$ moves upto $A$ is double the diameter of the circle.

I could not formulate the equation whose limiting value is to be found?Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad$[image]

Let $\theta=\angle TAP$, Then $AP=2R\sin\theta$ by the sine law, where $2R$ is the diameter of the circle.
Now, since $AT=AP$ we have $\angle QTA=\frac{\pi-\theta}{2}$ and consequently
$$\frac{AQ}{AT}=\tan\left(\frac{\pi-\theta}{2}\right)$$
It follows that
$$AQ=AT\cot\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)=2R(\sin\theta)\cot\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)
=4R\cos^2\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)$$
Hence, we have always $AQ\le 4R$, Moreover, $\lim\limits_{\theta\to0}AQ=4R$. This proves the result.

Comment: Hi. How have you written $\frac{AQ}{AT}=\tan\left(\frac{\pi-\theta}{2}\right)$?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Let $B\,$ be the other end point of the diameter through $A$ .

Put $\theta=\angle ABP$ and project orthogonally $P$ onto $AQ$ and $AT$ obtaining $P_1$ and $P_2$ respectively.

So (why ?)$$AQ=AT \cdot \frac {PP_2}{P_2T}$$ Use L'Hospital when computing the limit for $\theta \rightarrow 0$ .

Comment: Hi. Any chance you could clear my doubt on Omran's answer?